# Why my load more button won't work whatever I do?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I've been struggling with this the whole day, I just can't get it working for I don't know which reason. The doubt is because I have another section on the same page and it works perfectly.

I have a form, and when that form gets submitted I show results below without refresh with the help of AJAX. Now at the bottom I have a `Load More` button which should calculate all outputted results and limit them to 3. So when the `Load More` button is clicked it will show 3 more results and so on.

**My PHP + HTML:**

```
<?php 
$comments = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE feed_id='$feed_token' ORDER by posted_at DESC");
?> 
<div class="storelisting<?php echo $post_inc2; ?>" id="storelisting<?php echo $post_inc2; ?>">
<?php
while($comments_row = mysqli_fetch_array($comments)) {             
  $comment = $comments_row['comment'];
  $comments_posted_at = $comments_row['posted_at'];
  $user_token = $comments_row['user_id'];

  $user_firstname = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT firstname FROM users WHERE token='$user_token'");
  $user_username = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT username FROM users WHERE token='$user_token'");
  $user_logo = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT logo FROM users WHERE token='$user_token'");
  $comment_firstname = mysqli_fetch_row($user_firstname);
  $comment_username = mysqli_fetch_row($user_username);
  $comment_logo = mysqli_fetch_row($user_logo);
?>

<div class="comments">
  <div class="main">
    <figure class="user mb-0 mr-3"><img class="post-img-img comment-img" src="assets/img/user_images/<?php if ($comment_logo[0] == '') { echo 'user-top.png'; }  else { echo $comment_logo[0]; } ?>"></figure>
    <div>
      <h5 class="modal-title comments-modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle"><?php echo $comment_firstname[0]; ?><span class="bullet"> &sdot; </span><span class="comments-subtitles">@<?php echo $comment_username[0]; ?></span><span class="bullet"> &sdot; </span><span class="comments-subtitles"><?php echo timeago($comments_posted_at); ?></span></h5>
      <div class="modalUsername get-space">Replaying to <span class="reply-to">@<?php echo $username[0]; ?></span></div>
      <p class="commentMsg"><?php echo $comment; ?></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<?php } ?>

</div>

<div id="loadMoreComments<?php echo $post_inc2; ?>">Load More</div>
```

**jQuery (Updated):**

```
   $('.storelisting<?php echo $increase; ?> .comments').css('display','none');
$(document).ready(function () {
    size_li = $(".storelisting<?php echo $increase; ?> .comments").length;
    x=3;
    $('.storelisting<?php echo $increase; ?> .comments:lt('+x+')').show();
    if (size_li <= x) {
    $('#loadMoreComments<?php echo $increase; ?>').remove();
    }
    $('#loadMoreComments<?php echo $increase; ?>').click(function () {
        x= (x+3 <= size_li) ? x+3 : size_li;

        setTimeout(function(){
        $('.storelisting<?php echo $increase; ?> .comments:lt('+x+')').fadeIn("slow");
      }, 1000);

        if(x == size_li){
        setTimeout(function(){
          $('#loadMoreComments<?php echo $increase; ?>').hide();
        }, 1000);
        }
    });
});
```

So the PHP code gets all the rows from the selected column/table, that works great, with the AJAX I show submitted comments bellow, which works great too. But the Load more button doesn't do nothing when its clicked. The script shows only three divs and hide others, but when clicked it doesn't respond. The `$post_inc2` and the `$increase` variables increases the number on the divs (because I have multiple feeds that lets you comment on it).

Any help will mean a lot, since I'm really frustrated.

Comment: jQuery doesn't recognize the selectors which contain php variables...

Comment: I think thats not the case. With this variables i'm simply adding the number increment, I didn't showed whole code but in the load more script I have a while loop which shows this code multiple times (so it matches the .comments number in the form)

Comment: @WebMarie - they work the way the OP is trying to.  If `$increase = 1` then `$(".storelisting<?php echo $increase; ?> .comments")` would be the same as `$(".storelisting1 .comments")`

Comment: Ok, didn't know it's possible within the string of selector. Thanks

Comment: @FreelancerHelp - We need to know the values used for `$post_inc2` and `$increase`.  If they don't match at some point, that is probably your problem

Comment: @mtr.web Yes they are by default 1. So I'm using while loop first on my php code which retrives number of posts on which users can comment, then I'm using same while loop on my jquery so the $increase has the same number and so it matches with my php code, also I checked from console and the numbers are good. I will post my workaround which I now got, now it shows three results, when load more is clicked it shows three more but it stops there even tho there is more results. I will update my fiddle with new jquery code now.

Comment: So my code works good now it justs shows three results, then after clicking button it shows three more but then it stops, it hides load more button but there is more results. Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few pointers:

1. Oftentimes `.show()` won't do anything unless you do `.hide()` first, and vise versa. You can chain them, e.g. `$(el).hide().show()` ... it's probably this.
2. Otherwise make sure your selectors are working by assigning your `$('selector')` calls to a variable and then doing a `console.log(thatVar.length)` to make sure each of them got the number of results you expected.
3. Finally it's possible you are attempting to attach your click listener before the element is ready in DOM. Best practice is always to attach listeners either inline or (in your case) during a DOM ready event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  // all your JQuery code shown above
});
```